# Can Google Drive be integrated with Google App Engine UserService?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to build my first Google Drive app and I've started with the example project.
As it is using its own authentication stuff (OAuth2 etc.) I was wondering if there is an easy way to integrate this with the UserService in Google App Engine.
How can I e.g. use the MailService to send mails *on behalf of the current user* when using Google Drive authentication?

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of UserService at all in terms of Google Drive. The only way seems to be OAuth2.0